# Linux SSH logging via PUTTY

Tags: ssh, login, root, putty

I have Linux console, managed from Windows.

Can login to Linux console from `MSTSC` service of Windows, as `xrdp` is installed on Linux.
However I cannot login via Putty with SSH connection. It's displaying error as 'Access denied'.

This error started to occur after I abruptly stopped the execution of `rsync` operation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> which I started from Putty.

Logging in as user: root
Operating System: Fedora 13

What might have gone wrong?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the `ssh` service on the Linux box? Try `sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: what did you run `rsync` on? you might have overwritten some configuration (or changed some permissions in the home-directory) that now prevents you from logging in.

Comment: @terdon `bash: service: command not found`

Comment: @umläute I was running rsync to backup mounted directory on same box

Comment: Did you run the service command with `sudo`? Also try (as root or with sudo) `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

Comment: @terdon yes I did try with `sudo`

Comment: failed password, maybe mistyped? shiftlock, wrong keyboard .. try typing it in a text editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go in through your MSTSC connection to `xrdp` and from within there restart your SSH daemon service.

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart

-or-

$ sudo service sshd restart
```

If the problem continues then I'd consult the log file `/var/log/secure` to see if  you can see if it's an authentication issue. You can consult the log file `/var/log/messages` to confirm that the SSH service is functioning normally as well.

#### EDIT #1

Based on a comment from the OP, "..Failed password for root from 192.168.4.190 port 50677.." it looks like it could be the root user's password isn't what you think. Again using your MSTSC access via `xrdp` I'd confirm that you can `su -` and login as root.

If you can then the issue likely lies with either something in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file not allowing either user root access or the IP you're attempting to connect from might not be allowed access. I would expect different messaging in the `/var/log/*` log files however, but these are 2 additional leads to follow-up on.

Comment: I did try your service command but to no avail. and yes `/var/log/secure` display following messages

`Feb 20 21:21:36 localhost sshd[31052]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Feb 20 21:21:36 localhost sshd[31052]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Feb 20 21:22:39 localhost sshd[31054]: Failed password for root from 192.168.4.190 port 50677 ssh2
Feb 20 21:27:55 localhost sshd[31062]: Failed password for root from 192.168.4.190 port 50699 ssh2`

Comment: @AbhishekMadhani - see updates.

Answer (score 2):

ssh is configured with `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` it is possible to disable root from login via ssh in there. This question has answers that might help too.

[Permit root to login via ssh only with key-based authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99307/permit-root-to-login-via-ssh-only-with-key-based-authentication)

and this *opposite* question also provides some answers.

[How do I disable remote root login via ssh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8884/how-do-i-disable-remote-root-login-via-ssh)