# root login must be su instead of loginning directly in Redhat , how to set?

Tags: linux

In RedHat , I want to login with other user firstly in SSH, such as the user input when installing OS , then su - root , instead of being able to login with root directly in SSH How to set in command line and config files ? I have no UI .

Comment: I also want to be able to login with root by ssh , just should be su from other user in ssh , instead of login with root directly by ssh
such as : login with user1 in ssh, then "su - root" , input the password of root , then switched to root in ssh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable remote root login via ssh?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8884/how-do-i-disable-remote-root-login-via-ssh)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Next time, try a magical thing called search engine before asking.

See here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/security-tip-disable-root-ssh-login-on-linux/

Comment: Thanks , I searched before asking , But ... had not found , Worked now

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable root login you need to empty the `/etc/securetty` file so that the root user cant login via console for refrance here is the link [disable console root login](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s3-wstation-privileges-tty.html).